# NoReverseMatch at /stocks/5/

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

Django's reverse function is apparently not able to resolve my URL.

Here is my `urls.py` containing the urls

```
urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^login/$', views.loginview, name='login'),
    url(r'logout/$', views.logoutview, name='logout'),
    url(r'signup/$', views.signup, name='signup'),
    url(r'^stocks/(?P<pk>[0-9])/$', views.successful_login, name='successful_login'),
    url(r'^buystocks/(?P<pk>[0-9])/(?P<sn>[A-Z])/buy/$', views.buy, name='buy')
]
```

The snippet which contains the redirect to the URL is below.

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'buy' pk=user.id sn=stock.stock_name %}" >
```

The trace back is given below

```
NoReverseMatch at /stocks/5/
Reverse for 'buy' with keyword arguments '{u'pk': 5, u'sn': u'HDFC'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['buystocks/(?P<pk>[0-9])/(?P<sn>[A-Z])/buy/$']
```

Comment: Are your `pk`s in 0-9 range? Your current regex does not support numbers beyound 9, you should add a `+` after `[0-9]`

Comment: Yeah they are in the range 0-9 as of now, but still I will add a `+`.Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a little problem in your regular expressions and that is they just match with 1-character values. Take another look at them:

```
 (?P<pk>[0-9])/(?P<sn>[A-Z])
```

Without the fuss:

```
  [0-9]/[A-Z]
```

You need to add a `+` after the regex to fix the problem. i.e:

```
 (?P<pk>[0-9]+)/(?P<sn>[A-Z]+)
```

---

`+` means that the group or charachter preceding it have to appear one or more times. e.g:

`A` matches `A`, `A+` matches `A`, `AA`, `AAA`,... but not an empty string. 
`A*` matches an empty string in addition to everything that `A+` matches with.

A more generalized version of `*` and `+` is `{m, n}` operator which sets an upper and lower bound for the number of repetitions. With that notation `A{2,4}` only matches `AA`, `AAA` and `AAAA`. `A+` and `A*` can be rewritten as `A{1,}` and `A{0,}` respectively. Note that omitting the upper bound results in having no upper bound (in other words, upper bound is infinity)